# Mongodb error for duplicate indexes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to MongoDB/Mongoose and am in the process of dumping my localdb in order to create a DB for heroku.  When I run `mongorestore` I get the following error(s):

```
2016-08-29T22:05:00.411-0500    building a list of collections to restore from /Users/micahsherman/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r dir
2016-08-29T22:05:00.518-0500    reading metadata for heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations from /Users/micahsherman/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r/locations.metadata.json
2016-08-29T22:05:00.518-0500    reading metadata for heroku_n1kxxxxxx.test from /Users/micahsherman/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r/test.metadata.json
2016-08-29T22:05:00.519-0500    restoring heroku_n1kxxxxxx.test from /Users/micahsherman/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r/test.bson
2016-08-29T22:05:00.519-0500    restoring heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations from /Users/micahsherman/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r/locations.bson
2016-08-29T22:05:00.520-0500    restoring indexes for collection heroku_n1kxxxxxx.test from metadata
2016-08-29T22:05:00.574-0500    finished restoring heroku_n1kxxxxxx.test (0 documents)
2016-08-29T22:05:00.799-0500    error: multiple errors in bulk operation:
  - E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('57c334af05803d85c7b9e780') }
  - E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('57c3819605803d85c7b9e783') }

2016-08-29T22:05:00.799-0500    restoring indexes for collection heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations from metadata
2016-08-29T22:05:00.852-0500    finished restoring heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations (2 documents)
2016-08-29T22:05:00.852-0500    done
```

These prevent a connection from Heroku.

I have gone into the console and printed the indexes, here are the results:

```
rs-ds017886:PRIMARY> db.system.indexes.find();
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "heroku_n1kxxxxxx.test" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "coords" : "2dsphere" }, "name" : "coords_2dsphere", "ns" : "heroku_n1kxxxxxx.locations", "background" : true, "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2 }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "heroku_n1kxxxxxx.objectlabs-system" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "heroku_n1kxxxxxx.objectlabs-system.admin.collections" }
rs-ds017886:PRIMARY>
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about debugging this.  Thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `locations.bson` file to ensure you don't have duplicated documents (`'57c334af05803d85c7b9e780'` & `'57c3819605803d85c7b9e783'`). Looks like you're adding data before you create your indexes.

Here's an example of what I believe to be happening (hard to tell without seeing the data)

```
> db.people.insert({name: "Matt"})

WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.people.insert({name: "Matt"})

WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.people.createIndex({name: 1}, {unique: true})

{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.people.$name_1 dup key: { : \"Matt\" }",
    "code" : 11000
}
```

the `_id` field already contains the unique constraint